# Who initiates the reward claim transaction to delegated stake accounts?

Tags: staking

If we have a staking account (for example this one, [`98U`](https://solscan.io/account/98UUoVfhQUod7qDcBco9LmD5KXZroaY2RazJ9LFZLfFS), which delegates to [`Fii`](https://solscan.io/account/FiijvR2ibXEHaFqB127CxrL3vSj19K2Kx1jf2RbK4BWS)) we can see its staking and withdrawal authority at the time of this question is [`FF7`](https://solscan.io/account/FF7sQV8buDfdBPDUn4gJDEx3UspX7p2FmrNAogMfjpDc). However, if we look at the instructions actually claiming the staking rewards and adding them to 98U, we can see all of these transaction ([example](https://solscan.io/tx/Q6xLRYfC7yaPKCybyhtRQUwww9GafPdzNDq9RJhYGFnJSHbP9jcKL7KtHmssH53z19nU6rhLmokSZddfbbQSpUw)) are iniated by and paid for by [`GZc`](https://solscan.io/account/GZctHpWXmsZC1YHACTGGcHhYxjdRqQvTpYkb9LMvxDib) i.e. not the withdrawal/delegation authority of the staking account or the validator it's delegated to. Who is this account and what is their incentive for claiming the rewards every epoch (and seemingly for every stake account I can find)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically all reward have been collected at epoch boundaries. This led to performance problems because this basically took multiple seconds every epoch:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/20384

There were multiple improvements to this. For example increasing the minimun stake amount to 0.1 and collecting the fees over a longer time span.
https://github.com/orgs/solana-labs/projects/10

The address you are seeing is owned by Jito and the transactions you are seeing are probably the Jito MEV rewards.

https://jito-foundation.gitbook.io/mev/jito-solana/command-line-arguments

Comment: This answers my question & the github discussion addresses a few other things I was wondering about too! Thank you!

Comment: Note that the proposal was to increase the minimum stake amount to 1 SOL, but it hasn't been enabled yet. The 0.1 SOL proposal was never included in the code.